# How to solve datetime error in xlwings in python?

Tags: python, datetime, xlwings

I have written a code to fetch stock data from an api. I have tried to convert that data before transferring to xlsx format. But getting an error. This is my code......

```
    resjson = requests.get(url,headers=headers).json()
    candleinfo = resjson['data']['candles']
    columns = ['timestamp','Open','High','Low','Close','Volume','OI']
    df= pd.DataFrame(candleinfo,columns=columns)
    df['Name'] = tokens[index]
    df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], errors='coerce')
    df['Date'] = df['timestamp'].dt.date
    df['Time'] = df['timestamp'].dt.time   
    # df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], errors='coerce')      
    df=df[['Name','Date','Time','Open','High','Low','Close','Volume']]
    # df.to_csv("H:/Historical Minute Data/"+str(token)+".csv", index=False)
    # print(token)
    df1 = df.tail(1)
    #add one record per symbol, ie only the last record 
    if symbols_df is None:
        symbols_df = df1
    else:   
        symbols_df = symbols_df.append(df1, ignore_index=True)
    index = index + 1
    
    sht.range('A1').options(pd.DataFrame, header=1, index=False, expand='table').value = symbols_df
```

I have used xlwings to send this data to live excel sheet. I am getting a error like this........

TypeError: Objects of type 'datetime.time' can not be converted to a COM VARIANT

How to solve this??..Thanks in advance.

Comment: Adding support for Time has been an open issue since 2014: https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/issues/86

Comment: is there no solution?

Comment: Excel doesn't really have a time-only format. In reality, it is `1/0/1900  12:00:00` and formats it to only show time (noon as an example). So you could do this manually in your dataframe before sending it over, then format it as Time number format.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? I tested a pd.Timestamp from dt.datetime(2022,1,28,12,5,0) and it came into Excel as 12:05:00 PM.

```
df['Time'] = df['timestamp'].dt.time.astype('str')
```

Here is a full test I just did now.

```
import xlwings as xw
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
app = xw.App()
wb = app.books[0]
stamp = dt.datetime(2022,1,28,12,5,0)
df = pd.DataFrame([stamp], columns=['stamp'])
df['Time'] = df['stamp'].dt.time.astype('str')
sht = wb.sheets['Sheet1']
rng = sht.range('A1')
rng.value = df
```

Comment: it's not working......i have tried that.

Comment: What is not working? I used a new, blank workbook to test it on and it worked for me.

Comment: is it...astype(str) or astype('str')???

Comment: The latter. I just added a full test I just did right now.